# Split array value in table JSP

Tags: java, arrays, jsp

how i can split the array value for JSP, I am trying to split the array values and put in tables

```
 <%
        String query = request.getParameter("item");
    ItemSearch is = new ItemSearch();   
    ArrayList<Items> result = is.doSearch(query);
    for(Items item : result)
    {   
        out.println(item.getImg());
        out.println(item.getHref());
        out.println(item.getTitle());
        out.println(item.getPrice());
        out.println(item.getDesc());
        //out.println(item.toString());

    }

    %>
```

this is my table.

```
<table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= out.println(item.getDesc)%></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
```

can anyone help me with this coding. how can i call each item

Comment: print your html in the print statements

Comment: you wrote you want to split values, are you talking about looping on your `item` array to display each Item in a row?

Comment: @jhamon yes i talkin about looping and how to display in tabel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<%
String query = request.getParameter("item");
ItemSearch is = new ItemSearch();   
ArrayList<Items> result = is.doSearch(query);
for(Items item : result)
{   
    %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= item.getDesc) %></td>
    <td><%= item.getTitle() %></td>
    <td><%= item.getPrice() %></td>
   </tr>
   <%
}
%>
</table>
```

**But**

Using Scriplets is dinosaur-technology. You should no longer use that. Instead use EL for example

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<c:forEach var="item" items="${yourListAsBean}">
<tr>
  <td><c:out value="${item.desc}" /></td>
  <td><c:out value="${item.title}" /></td>
  <td><c:out value="${item.price}" /></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you. It work but can i ask you, what supposed i put ${yourListAsBean}

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `foreach of jstl` like this:
Add these `taglib`:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>  
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

And code for displaying data

```
   <c:forEach begin="0" end="${fn:length(result) - 1}" var="idx">
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th><td><c:out value="${result[idx]}"/></td>
      <th>Name</th><td><c:out value="${result[idx]}"/></td>
      <th>Price</th><td><c:out value="${result[idx]}"/></td>
   </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```